# Lotus Notes change sendTo after GetDocumentByUNID

Tags: vba, excel, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

trying to change sendTo recipients form Excel vba, a part of code is:

```
Set MailDoc = Maildb.GetDocumentByUNID(strMemoUNID)
Set rtiSig = MailDoc.GetFirstItem("Body")
Set rtiNew = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("rtiTemp")
Call rtiNew.AppendText(strBody): rtiNew.AddNewLine (1)
strToArray(0) = "aaa@xxx.com"
MailDoc.SendTo = strToArray
MailDoc.CopyTo = strCCArray
MailDoc.BlindCopyTo = strBccArray
MailDoc.subject = strSubject
Call rtiNew.AppendRTItem(rtiSig)
Call MailDoc.RemoveItem("Body")
Set rtitem = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
Call rtitem.AppendRTItem(rtiNew)
MailDoc.Save False, False
Set uiMemo = ws.EditDocument(True, MailDoc)
```

But only changing `MailDoc.subject`

Why not changing `MailDoc.SendTo` ?

Comment: I know, but I need to change in this place

Comment: Does it work if you set field "EnterSendTo" in addition to "SendTo"?

Comment: Yes, it works now, please make an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set field "**EnterSendTo**" in addition to "SendTo".

This field is used in Notes email form "Memo" to edit the recipients "SendTo".

Comment: ++ Learnt something new today :)